# Replication from SQL Server Express Database to SQL Server Standard Database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

Is it possible to set up a replication between an SQL Server Express Database that we can't touch, with an SQL Server Standard database?

We only have read-only access on the SQL Server Express database, so we are oblige to use only SQL requests.
We thought of using a python script and doing the replication ourselves, but is there a framework that can do that ?

We don't need realtime replication, a time span of minutes is enough.

Comment: Can you set up a link to the express database?

Comment: We can only use SQL requests on the express databasse ... :(